# How to generate exe from winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, code-generation, exe

I want to know how can I generate .exe file with my C# winforms application?

Let's say the user want to create his own app through my winforms app. He will have options to put custom title, custom text in already created labels/textboxes and etc. in his own application.

How can I do this?

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you want an application that generate EXE (executable WinForm application) that holds specific information. Why wouldn't you use configuration file. a text file from which such information is read and loaded up once the application is run. the configuration file can be INI / XML / .properties, etc.

Comment: Can you explain how you are going to use this? Maybe alternatives to what you are trying to achieve could be used?

Comment: And do you need to provide access to databases, online resources etc?

Comment: If the user only customizes the interface, you can save the customization to a new app.config and copy both exe and app.config to a new folder.

Comment: An example of what I want is Keygen creator. The user can choose background image, can add serial keys, pick some random text for the labels, title and that's it.

PS: Hope my example doesn't violate the rules of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the CSharpCodeProvider is to use the classes in the [System.Reflection.Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd5fw18y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) namespaces, by starting with [AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs22fky4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) you can construct an assembly which can then be saved to disk (by using [AssemblyBuilder.Save(string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8zwdfdeh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

If there are only a few customizations the user can make, of which their functionality is known before hand, use a config file where the various options can be defined. Use the [ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to edit the application configuration for other executables.

For example:

```
var targetConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("MyOtherApplication.exe");
var uiOptions = targetConfig.Sections["UIOptions"];
uiOptions["TitleText"] = _titleTextBox.Text;
targetConfig.Save();
```

Then the other application can read it out by using the same keys:

```
var myUIOptions = (ConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("UIOptions");
this.Caption = uiOptions["TitleText"] as string;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just customize your app user can create some xml file:

```
<title>user title</title>
<textbox name="customName"></textbox>
```

Than you can read this file and add controls to some field on your app.